# Accessing new data type elements

Tags: haskell

Okay so i have this new type

```
    data Person = Pers {
    vorname,
    nachname :: String,
    geburtstag :: Geburtstag } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

with

```
    type Tag = Int
    data Monat = Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | Mai | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Okt | Nov | Dez deriving (Eq, Show)
    type Jahr = Int
    data Geburtstag = Gtg Tag Monat Jahr deriving (Eq, Show)

    type Eintrag = (Person, Anschrift, SozNr)
```

i need to know how i can access the elements, like geburtstag and those from it (tag,monat,jahr)

For example i am given an Eintrag and i need to access geburtstag or even Monat from geburtstag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
myDate = Gtg 7 Jan 2013
myPerson = Person "Joe" "Bloe" myDate
myEintrag = (myPerson, ???, ???) -- I don't know what Anschrift and SozNr look like
```

Here are some examples of how you access them:

```
putStrLn $ show (vorname myPerson)
putStrLn $ show (nachname myPerson)

let (a, _, _) = myEintrag
putStrLn $ show (nachname a)
let (Gtg d m y) = geburtstag a
putStrLn $ show y
```

If you used named fields on `Geburtstag` and `Eintrag` as you did with `Person`, it might be more convenient (depending on your application). Otherwise, you have to pattern match on those fields, as I've done here.

---

EDIT: You say you already have getPerson, which I assume looks something like this:

```
getPerson :: Eintrag -> Person
getPerson (p, _, _) = p
```

So in my example, `getPerson myEintrag` would return `myPerson`.

You don't need to write a function to extract the geburtstag from a person; naming the field gives you that function automatically. So `geburtstag (getPerson myEintrag)` would extract the geburtstag from a Person. From there, you could define functions such as:

```
getDay :: Geburtstag -> Int
getDay (Gtg d _ _) = d
```

And then `getDay (geburtstag (getPerson myEintrag))`, or equivalently, `getDay . geburtstag . getPerson $ myEintrag` would get you the day from the Eintrag.

Comment: okay, but i have just myEintrag how can i access Geburtstag from it. I made a first function to give me Person from Eintrag but now i do not know how to get Geburtstag from Person, since it doesnt work with pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

```
    getGtag :: Person -> Geburtstag
    getGtag (Pers a b c) = c
```

Comment: You don't need this function, because the fields of `Person` are named. So `geburtstag p` returns the `geburtstag` of `p`.